# How to make a remote modal using semantic ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, semantic-ui

Using bootstrap I can open a modal with a remote content using *href*:

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="example.html" data-target="#example">Example</a></li>
```

How can I make it using Semantic UI? The official web site only teaches how to open a modal like that:

```
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could try this approach - it's something I came up with to allow loading of a remote html page into a Semantic UI modal.

You use a anchor tag with a hyperlink that links to your remote page and then pull in the content of the remote page to populate your modal.  This will work for multiple anchor tags on a page, so useful for information modals that pop-up when the click to give them info or something like that.

Here's the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.info-modal-link').each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {                   
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    $('.info.modal .content').html(data);
                    $(".info.modal").modal({closable:true,observeChanges:true}).modal('show');
                });
            });              
        });
   });
</script>
```

Then in your page you need the markup for the modal (I have it without a header):

```
<div class="ui small info modal">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

And then your hyperlink to trigger the modal:

```
 <a href="/yourremotepage.html" class="info-modal-link">Find out more</a>
```

It's a bit rough and ready, and I've no idea how it will perform, but it does the job.